# NamedPipeClientStream throws UnauthorizedAccessException on Connect

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have the same problem everyone else has when connecting a "write" pipe to a running service: UnauthorizedAccessException. I tried every solution and nothing can make it connect successfully.

The scenario is having a low-integrity C#/WPF app running in system tray that gets notifications from a Windows Service using named pipes and can tell the service to cancel certain operations or wait for more data (which is why it needs a write pipe to the service). Reading from service's pipe works fine, and I am using two pipe objects (one from service to client and another from client to service).

The service runs under a domain user's account, but the pipe fails to connect no matter what it runs under, including Local System.

Server pipes are created like so:

```
PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();

// Production service runs under current user credentials.
ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite | PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance, AccessControlType.Allow));

// Test service runs under local system credentials.
ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite | PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance, AccessControlType.Allow));

// Add world just for the hell of it, still won't work.
ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

this.readPipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(clientPipeName, PipeDirection.In);
this.writePipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(serverPipeName, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.None, 1024, 1024, ps);
```

Client pipes are created like so:

```
this.readPipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", serverPipeName, PipeDirection.In);
this.writePipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", clientPipeName, PipeDirection.Out);

// This doesn't make a difference.
//this.writePipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", clientPipeName, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, PipeOptions.None, TokenImpersonationLevel.None, HandleInheritability.None);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't want to leave this open, since this was solved and following code is in production.

- Server pipe must have ACL list carefully constructed to allow connections from low-integrity client pipes, as long as users are authenticated or administrators. See CreateNativePipeSecurity().
- Client pipe is created as usual

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates the client and server pipes.
  /// </summary>
  private void CreatePipes()
  {
      string serverPipeName = string.Format("{0}server", this.pipeName);
      string clientPipeName = string.Format("{0}client", this.pipeName);

      if (this.readPipe != null)
      {
          this.readPipe.Dispose();
      }

      if (this.writePipe != null)
      {
          this.writePipe.Dispose();
      }

      if (this.server)
      {
          // Create a write pipe for sending notifications to client.
          this.writePipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(clientPipeName, PipeDirection.Out);

          // Create a read pipe for receiving notifications from the client.
          // Creating a pipe to high integrity process from low integrity process requires native access list creation (.NET bug).
          NativeMethods.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttributes = this.CreateNativePipeSecurity();
          IntPtr securityAttributesPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(securityAttributes));
          Marshal.StructureToPtr(securityAttributes, securityAttributesPtr, false);

          string nativePipeName = string.Format(@"\\.\pipe\{0}", serverPipeName);

          SafePipeHandle nativePipe = NativeMethods.CreateNamedPipe(
              nativePipeName,
              NativeMethods.PipeOpenMode.PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND,
              0,
              NativeMethods.PipeInstances.PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
              0,
              0,
              NativeMethods.PipeWait.NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER,
              securityAttributesPtr);

          int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

          Marshal.FreeHGlobal(securityAttributesPtr);

          if (nativePipe.IsInvalid)
          {                    
              throw new Win32Exception(error);
          }

          this.readPipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.In, false, false, nativePipe);
      }
      else
      {
          // Create a read pipe for receiving notifications from server.
          this.readPipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", clientPipeName, PipeDirection.In);

          // Create a write pipe for sending notifications to the server.
          this.writePipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", serverPipeName, PipeDirection.Out);
      }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Generate security attributes to allow low integrity process to connect to high integrity service.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>A structure filled with proper attributes.</returns>
  private NativeMethods.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES CreateNativePipeSecurity()
  {
      // Define the SDDL for the security descriptor.
      string sddl = "D:" +        // Discretionary ACL
          "(A;OICI;GRGW;;;AU)" +  // Allow read/write to authenticated users
          "(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)";     // Allow full control to administrators

      IntPtr securityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;

      if (NativeMethods.ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
          sddl, 1, out securityDescriptor, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
      {
          throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
      }

      NativeMethods.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new NativeMethods.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
      sa.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);
      sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = securityDescriptor;
      sa.bInheritHandle = 0;

      return sa;
  }
  ```

Comment: Also have a look here: <https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ce43c90-00da-47e6-8e8c-4fdb2f7cc13e/named-pipe-error-systemunauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-denied?forum=netfxnetcom>: PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
PipeAccessRule psRule = new PipeAccessRule(@"Everyone", PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
ps.AddAccessRule(psRule);
 NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("datapipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 1, 1, ps);

Comment: What nuget or library did you use for NativeMethods?

Comment: @spmoolman those are API imports and declarations automatically generated by pinvoke.net

Comment: In my case, I discovered that PipeDirection.Out on the NamedPipeServerStream will produce the exception mentioned in the title for the client regardless of how PipeSecurity is setup. Even though my pipe server only wrote to the pipe and never read from it.