# Interaction between WPF and UWP by named pipes

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, named-pipes, sid

I'm trying create XBox Game Bar application (UWP). It has to receive some data from main WPF app. I use named pipes as it's described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/game-bar/guide/communicating-apps).
WPF creates server stream this way:

```
PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));
using (var pipe = NamedPipeServerStreamAcl.Create("PipesOfPiece", PipeDirection.InOut, 1,
                       PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.None, 0, 0, pipeSecurity))
{
      pipe.WaitForConnection();
}
```

And UWP app creates client:

```
_clientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream("PipesOfPiece");
_clientStream.Connect();
```

On

> _clientStream.Connect()

UWP app get error: *System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied*.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: did you create the right  `ACL` (access control list) to allow access to this named pipe by other apps/processess? see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37996868/14973743

Comment: also, instead of InOut for pipe direction, try using `In` alone.